# Is there a way in mongoDB using db.runCommand, where i can insert multiple doc in collection only it's not present. if present, ignore that document

Tags: mongodb, nosql, database-migration

I am writing a migration script, which uses a `db.runCommand` to apply migration in mongoDb.

Something like this:

```
 db.runCommand(
      {
         insert: "countries",
         documents: [
          {
            "name": "Algeria"
          },
          {
            "name": "Andorra"
          },
          {
            "name" : "Angola"
          }
        ]
      }
    )
```

let's say if Algeria is already present and Andorra along with Angola is not present in `countries` collection.
My requirement is we should be able to only insert only Andorra and Angola in countries collection as they are not present. Algeria should be ignored and no exception should be thrown.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, I'll start with my preferred option:

I would start by creating a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on the `name` field.
Now when you try to insert a document that violates the uniqueness constraint it fails:

> Inserting a duplicate value for any key that is part of a unique index, ... With ordered to false, the insert operation would continue with any remaining documents.

Let's understand how that affects the `insert` command via the `ordered` [option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/insert/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.insert):

> Optional. If true, then when an insert of a document fails, return without inserting any remaining documents listed in the inserts array. If false, then when an insert of a document fails, continue to insert the remaining documents. Defaults to true.

This means that if you use the `ordered: false` option for the `insert` command, all inserts will "try" to execute even if one fails (in our case due to unique index violation).

To summarise what you have to do is 1. build a unique index on the `name` field, 2. add `ordered: false` option to the insert command like so:

```
db.runCommand(
    {
        insert: "countries",
        documents: [
            {
                "name": "Algeria"
            },
            {
                "name": "Andorra"
            },
            {
                "name": "Angola"
            }
        ],
        ordered: false
    }
)
```

The other option you have is to use an [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.update) command with the `upsert` option instead of the `insert` command, I would personally not choose this as it has more overhead:

```
db.runCommand(
    {
        update: "countries",
        updates: [
            {
                q: {"name": "Algeria"},
                u: {"name": "Algeria"},
                upsert: true
            },
            {
                q: {"name": "Andorra"},
                u: {"name": "Andorra"},
                upsert: true
            },
            {
                q: {"name": "Angola"},
                u: {"name": "Angola"},
                upsert: true
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: The first option is good, but the problem is dbRunCommand will still return an error, in case if there are documents that are already present and as such, the migration library (migrate/mongodb.go) think that migration is not applied successfully and it will stop other migrations which are in pipeline.

Comment: Can you add error handling and avoid DuplicateKeyError? otherwise you'll have to use the update option which as i said adds overhead.

Comment: Unfortunately, error handling is done by the library itself, and if any such error occurs, it updates schema_migrations collection with dirty as true. I have no control over it. Looks like the second option is the only feasible one without any error. thanks a lot.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert, I am trying to do a similar update and is not working, `db.runCommand(
   {
     explain: {
        update: "Test",
        updates: [
           {
               q: { "fid": "1111" },
               u: { $set: { "fid": "1111", "origin": "SKD" }},
      upsert: true
           }
        ]
     }
   }
)`